# Find constant $k$ in matrix so that matrix $A$ is orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

### Problem

Find constant $k\in \mathbb{R}$ in matrix so that matrix $A$ is orthogonal when:

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & -7 \\ 1 & 3 & -1 \\ 2 & -1 & k \end{bmatrix} $$

### Attempt to solve

A matrix is orthogonal when $AA^T=A^TA=I$, where $I$ is identity matrix. By utilizing this fact we should be able to solve constant k

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & -7 \\ 1 & 3 & -1 \\ 2 & -1 & k \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 2 \\ -1 & 3 & -1 \\ -7 & -1 & k \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 51 & 5 & 3-7k \\ 5 & 11 & -k -1 \\ 3-7k & -k-1 & k^2+5 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}  $$

It looks like something that could not be solved, but am i simply wrong ?

Comment: Check your question!

Comment: I don't think i understand what you mean ? @gimusi

Comment: It seems that your question can't be "Find constant  k  in matrix so that matrix  A  is orthogonal". Are you sure that the question is not different?

Comment: Tuki, you are not using the word "orthogonal " consistently. There is a value of $k$ that makes the COLUMNS of your matrix pairwise orthogonal. In order to get an orthogonal matrix, you must then divide the columns by, let's see, $\sqrt 6,$ then $\sqrt {11}$ for the middle column, and a different square root for the thrid column

Comment: short version: each column in an orthogonal matrix, considered as a vector, has length exactly one.